# Feeding values to Iterator "from inside"

Tags: scala, iterator

I want to do something like this in Scala.

```
def getFancyIterator: Iterator[Int] = {
  ... { /// Some arbitrary logic goes here: conditionals, loops, whatever
    ... { 
      ... {
        val x = ...
        // Then at some point I call this:
        feedNext(x)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, from the outside all that should look like normal iterator, so that I could do, for example:

```
getFancyIterator.foreach(println)
```

The trick of course is, that I do not want to store all those values in a collection at any point in time. In other words, I want my `getFancyIterator` function to "feed" iterator's `next()` values "on demand".

<strike>I'm sure there must be some (embarrassingly) simple way to do just that, but somehow it doesn't come to my mind..</strike>

**UPDATE:**
In essence I want to do `yield x`, but not just from normal `for` loop, but from some arbitrary piece of code.

Comment: If `feedNext` returns an `Iterator[Int]` you should be fine. What does it actually return?

Comment: No, the whole function `getFancyIterator` returns and iterator. `feedNext` just marks the place, where I want to "feed" the next value to the resulting iterator.

Comment: Thanks for edit, Daniela

Comment: `for-yield` in Scala doesn't create an iterator, it's just syntax sugar for `map` and `flatMap`.

Comment: Now I'm starting to think, this is not possible at all, because my "arbitrary logic" should somehow block and wait for `next()` call on my iterator. Probably I'll have to redesign my logic so, that it generates items by one.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement the Iterator interface directly, and use `next()` to return your `feedNext(x)` value:

```
def getFancyIterator: Iterator[Int] = new Iterator[Int] {
  def hasNext = true //or some other flag to determine when you are done.
  def next():Int = {
    //some fancy logic goes here to calculate x
    1
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I finally resorted to something like this. However my original idea was to do it backwards - my fancy logic generates xs and "feeds" them through some special method `feedNext`. And then the outside user of the iterator would take these values whenever he needs by calling `next()` on the iterator. However I didn't succeed to implement this idea. It probably could be done with some asynchronous actors sending xs on request as messages, but that would be way too complex for my case.